# How to get class of generic type in Spring

Tags: java, spring, generics

I have a generics class DAO in my spring project,I have to get class of generic T.I know the pure java solution:

```
class Foo<T> {
    final Class<T> typeParameterClass;

    public Foo(Class<T> typeParameterClass) {
        this.typeParameterClass = typeParameterClass;
    }

    public void bar() {
        // you can access the typeParameterClass here and do whatever you like
    }
}
```

But,in spring project,I have to get the Foo from the "ApplicationContext",I can't get Foo by:

```
Foo<ClassName> foo = new Foo<ClassName>(ClassName.class);
```

How to get class of generic type  in Spring.

Comment: `@Autowired private Foo<ClassName>;` http://spring.io/blog/2013/12/03/spring-framework-4-0-and-java-generics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring is able to use constructors with parameters

In java configuration, it is very simple :

```
@Configuration
public class MyConf {
    ...
    @Bean
    private foo() {
        return new Foo<ClassName>(ClassName.class);
    }
    ...
}
```

It is also possible with XML config

```
<bean id="foo" class="...Foo">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.Class" value="...ClassName"/>
</bean>
```