# How to get class of a Generic Type Class in Java

Tags: java, generics

> **N.B: If you find this duplicate then please read the bottom text first.**

### Code Overview

**MyClass**

```
public class MyClass<E> {
    E element;
}
```

---

**ClassTwo**

```
public class ClassTwo<E> {
    E[] collections;

    public ClassTwo(Class<E> c, int size) {
        collections = (E[]) Array.newInstance(c, size);
    }
}
```

---

**Tester**

```
public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassTwo<MyClass<E>> two = new ClassTwo<MyClass<E>>(MyClass<E>.class, 10); // This causes an error
        ClassTwo<MyClass<E>> two2 = new ClassTwo<MyClass<E>>(MyClass.class, 10); // This also causes an error
    }
}
```

### Question Description

For normal classes we can use `ClassName.class` to get the class of that class but how can we get the class of a generic type classes. For example:

`MyClass.class` gives `Class<MyClass>`

but why we cannot use `MyClass<E>.class` to get `Class<MyClass<E>>`?

---

### Brief of Research

1. [Instantiating a generic class in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090458/instantiating-a-generic-class-in-java)
2. [How to get class of generic type in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26376638/how-to-get-class-of-generic-type-in-spring)
3. [Class Java, API 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html)
4. [Class Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2)
5. [How to get a class instance of generics type T](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437897/how-to-get-a-class-instance-of-generics-type-t)
6. [Incompatible types: Class cannot be converted to Class where CAP#1 is a fresh-type variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37736824/incompatible-types-classbar-cannot-be-converted-to-classcap1-where-cap1-i)
7. [Java Generics Example Tutorial – Generic Method, Class, Interface](https://www.journaldev.com/1663/java-generics-example-method-class-interface)

---

### Clarification

After looking through the books and internet for a long time for getting my answer, I failed to found a solution matches my question or anything similar that I would use to solve the problem.

N.B: If you find my question is a duplicate of any other question please instead of down-voting refer me to the question. If advised I can delete my questing in case of duplicate question.

Comment: It is important to realize the limitations of generics: there is no difference between the classes of `new ArrayList<String>()` and `new ArrayList<Integer>()`: they are both simply `ArrayList`s, and the class for both is `ArrayList.class`. The `<String>` bit is simply an instruction to the compiler to prevent you adding anything that's not a `String` (or null) to the list, and to assume that anything you get out can be cast to `String`.

Comment: Oh. Thank you! So for that, since there cannot be any class like `Class<MyClass<E>>` then how can I solve the compile error that shows and get what I want.